# Variables reset when render a piece of html

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, livesearch

i´m very new using django and in programming itself and i'm having some trouble rendering properly my templates.

I managed to create a live search from my oracle DB using Ajax and JQuery.

Currently i'm trying to add the names that my live search brings into an array and then pass it to the back end and do some more stuff with it but each time i search a new name, my array is emptied. Also if my livesearch brings more than one result, each time i try to add it to my array, it creates a new one instead of adding it

This are my templates:

```
base.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script></script>
    <title>Gestion de tiendas para usuarios</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}    

</body>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js" %}"></script>
<script>
    var users_to_be_added = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#livesearch").on('input', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            search_text = $("#livesearch").val()
            // console.log(search_text)
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'livesearch/',
                data: { text: search_text },
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#results").html(res);
                    console.log(res)
                }
            })
        })
        $("#agregar_usuario").click(function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            let user_picked = $("#users option:selected").text();                
            if (jQuery.inArray(user_picked, users_to_be_added) !== -1) {
                alert("El usuario ya se encuentra seleccionado")
            }
            else {
                users_to_be_added.push(user_picked);
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'add_users/',
                    data: { users_preselected: users_to_be_added },
                    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
                    },
                    success: function (res) {
                        $("#list_users").html(res);
                        console.log(res)
                    }
                })  
            }            
            console.log(users_to_be_added);
            // $("#users").empty();
        })
    })
</script>
</html>
```

user_selector.html

```
<select id="users">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Seleccionar Usuario</option>
    {% for u in list_users %}    
    <option value="{{u.NAME}}">{{u.NAME}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Busque Un Usuario Aqui</h1>
<input type="text" id="livesearch" placeholder="Buscar Usuario Aqui"><span><button id="agregar_usuario">Agregar Usuario</button></span><br>
<label for="userNames">Elija un usuario:</label>
<div id='results'>
    {% include "user_selector.html" %}
</div>

<div id="list_users">
    {% include "users_list_tobe_added.html" %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

users_list_tobe_added.html

```
<h4>Lista de usuarios</h4>
{{added_users}}  
<ul id="users_preselected">
    <!-- {% for u in added_users %}    
    <li value="{{u}}">{{u}}</li>
    {% endfor %} -->
</ul>
```

views.py

```
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, "home.html", {})


def livesearch(request):
    # print(request)
    searchtext = request.POST.get('text')
    searchtext = str(searchtext).upper()
    print(searchtext)
    # if len(searchtext) > 3:
    query = 'query that gets user'
    clean_list = []
    cursor = method_that_get_cursor()
    results = cursor.execute(query)
    for row in results:
        for key in cursor.description:
            clean_list.append({key[0]: value for value in row})
    # list_users = pd.DataFrame(users)
    # print(clean_list)
    print(type(clean_list))
    context = {
        "list_users": clean_list
    }
    return render(request, 'user_selector.html', context)


def add_users(request):
    # print(request)
    users_preselected = request.POST.get('users_preselected[]')
    print(type(users_preselected))
    context = {
        "added_users": users_preselected
    }
    return render(request, 'users_list_tobe_added.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from add_users.views import home_view, livesearch, add_users

urlpatterns = [
    path('livesearch/', livesearch, name='livesearch'),
    path('add_users/', add_users, name='add_users'),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: If you need to compare every new data with previously save data then `var users_to_be_added = [];` this should be outside event handler because currently whenever user click `agregar_usuario` array is empty i.e: `[]` so nothing happens .

Comment: thanks @Swati, it worked just like you suggested. Many thanks for the hint!